# Case Insensitive search with POstgres Similar To

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have such query in my Django code

```
cond = self.text_query(field.id, f'''
                                        EXISTS(
                                            SELECT *
                                            FROM {self.fieldvalue_db_view}
                                            WHERE entry_id = {self.db_table}.id AND
                                                                    {self.fieldvalue_db_view}.field_id = {field.id} AND
                                                                    {self.fieldvalue_db_view}.{text_search_column} SIMILAR TO %(pattern)s
                                        )
                                    ''', dict(pattern='%' + val + '%'))
```

When

```
val = '%%john smith%%' or val = '%%john%smith%%'
```

it did not return a result like 'John smith', but if

```
val = '%%john%smith%|%smith%john%%'
```

it returns results with 'John smith'.

How this case sensitiveness can be solved?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you consider to convert val to upper and then compare it to the upper result ? So you compare upper letters with upper letters and all results will be returned ...

Comment: No, I want to give some words and get all results which contain all those words in any order and case insensitively

Comment: What if there are 3 words ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ilike`:

```
EXISTS(
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        { self.fieldvalue_db_view }
    WHERE
        entry_id = { self.db_table }.id
        AND { self.fieldvalue_db_view }.field_id = { field.id }
        AND { self.fieldvalue_db_view }.{ text_search_column } ILIKE %(pattern) s
)
```

also you don't need to return all columns when you checking existence of a row , instead pass a constant which is cheaper

Comment: can I use ILIKE and multiple conditions?

Comment: I want to input some words and get all results containing that words in any order and without case insensitiveness

Comment: hmmmm... that would be not easy using like or pattern search , you might look for `full text search` instead .